# Replace array key value

Tags: php, arrays, replace, key

I want to replace array values (1, 2, 3 and 4) to corresponding text

```
1 = OK;
2 = nOK;
3 = Warning;
4 = Other
```

Here is some code:

```
$status = $row['status'];
```

(I stored $status text in mysql row 1,2,3,4,1,2,4,4,1, etc)

```
$myarray = array($status);
foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
{
    print_r($val);
}
```

Output of this is:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 3 [7] => 4 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 )
```

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: elaborate your question: what's your input, is it string or array? Be more exact

Comment: Where does the text come from and what does the original array look like? You haven't given us close to enough info.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question

Comment: Create an array with: `$statuses[1 => 'OK', 2 => 'nOK', ...']` and just do a `echo $statuses[$row['status']];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray= array_flip($oldArray);
```

This will give your array keys the values of your "values".
If i understood correct the "text" you are referring to is the array values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
$string_array = array(
                    1 => "OK",
                    2 => "nOK",
                    3 => "Warning",
                    4 => "Other"
                );
$output = array_flip($string_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `$myarray` is multi dimensional array the use the following code

```
$array = [
    1 => 'OK'
    2 => 'nOK'
    3 => 'warning'
    4 => 'Other'
];

foreach($myarray as $key => $subarray)
{
    foreach($subarray as $ele)
    print_r($array[$ele]);
}
```

Comment: I can't even see how this code works. Not to mention the syntax errors. Can you make a running version of this? Also it only works if it's one level multidimensional.

Comment: @Andreas as you can see in the question, the output of the print statement is an array, which tells that `$myarray` is multidimentional array

Comment: Yes. ok but where is the replacement OP asks about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace for this.
Str_replace accepts arrays and means you don't have to loop.

```
$repl =  array(1 =>"OK", 2 => "nOK", 3 => "Warning", 4 => "Other");

$myarray = array(1,2,3,4);

$new = str_replace($myarray,$repl, $myarray);

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/tgL1q